# Flink SQL : UDTF passes Row type parameters

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

```
CREATE TABLE user_log (
    data ROW(id String,user_id String,class_id String)
) WITH (
    'connector.type' = 'kafka',
    ...
);

INSERT INTO sink
SELECT * FROM user_log as tab,
LATERAL TABLE(splitUdtf(tab.data)) AS T(a,b,c);
```

UDTF Code:

```
public void eval(Row data) {...}
```

Can the **eval** method only pass Row type parameters? I want to get the key of Row in SQL,such as **id,user_id,class_id**,But the key of **Row in java** is index (such as 0,1,2).How do i do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your sql able to directly convert kafka data to table Row? Maybe not .
Row is the  type at the DataStream level, not the type in TableAPI&SQL.

If the data you received from kafka is in json format, you can use the DDL statement in fllink sql or use the Connector API to directly extract the fields in json, as long as your json is  in  key-value format.